# Facebox - Facebox popup not showing FB Like button

Tags: popup, facebook-like, facebox

I'm trying to display FB like button into facebox popup, but it is not working consistently for me, after opening popup multiple times, fb like button appears.

I also tried it with FB Like button - Iframe code, it works perfectly but in that case not able to fire edge create event.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you elaborate more? show us some code? are these popups load remote HTML? or hidden DIVs?

Comment: not loading hidden divs, only problem with the parsing, I have to refresh popup 3 times then it will appear.

Comment: Can you show us some code? I have it working on the *quick* example that I've just created locally.

Comment: Thanks ifaour for looking into this issue, here is the code,

What I did, display a custom fblike button image in facebox popup and onclick call facebook login , get all extended permissions from user 

Like this,

Comment: <div id="login1" class="login_button_area" ><div class="custom_fb_button"><input type=\"image\" id=\"fb-login-button\" src="'+custom_fblike_button+'" alt=\"Login with facebook\" onClick=\"FB.login(function (response){  if (response.session){if (response.authResponse){PutFBLike();}}else { sa_fb_login();}},{scope:\'publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_interests,user_likes\'});return false;\" /></div></div>


After granting permission, I am replacing custom image with real fb like button code with jquery, like below.

Comment: $saobject(document).ready(function() {   $saobject(".login_button_area").html("I m here....<div class=\'fb-like\' data-send=\'false\' data-href=\'https://www.facebook.com/footwearetc\' data-layout=\'button_count\' data-width=\'150\' data-show-faces=\'false\'></div>"); 
});

After executing above line, instead of showing real facebook like button it shows me only the text "I m here...", its replaced the like button code but like button doesn't appear into facebox popup. It will appear after reopen facebox popup 3 times.

Comment: Please try to place your code in your original question with the right formatting to make it easier for us to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution, problem was with the parsing...

Instead of parse only div where I was added like button code,
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("login1"));

I have just parse like below,
FB.XFBML.parse();

Now like button get display and